# Django appears to be caching function generating UUID for a model object

Tags: django, django-models, uuid

I'm using the following code to generate a UUID for every new instance of a model object:

```
def make_uuid(type):
    """Takes an entity type identifier string as input and returns a hex of UUID2 with a 
    type identifier pre-pended for readability"""

    return str(type)+str(uuid.uuid1().hex)
```

Model field:

```
account_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=34, default=make_uuid('AC'), db_index=True, unique=True)
```

When I actually run the app, the first attempt works great, but the second and all subsequent attempts fail with the following message:

> Exception Type:   IntegrityError
>
> Exception Value:   duplicate key value violates unique constraint
>   "accounts_accounts_account_uuid_key"

Any ideas as to what might be going on?

Comment: Edit `unique=True` to `null=True` http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30927563/django-1-8-default-option-only-executes-external-function-once#answer-30927966

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are passing the result of a make_uuid call instead of a callable object to default.

Your code equals the code below.

```
default_uuid = make_uuid('AC')
account_uuid = models.CharField(max_length=34, default=default_uuid, db_index=True, unique=True)
```

[Field.default](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/ref/models/fields/#django.db.models.Field.default):

> The default value for the field. This can be a value or a callable
>   object. If callable it will be called every time a new object is
>   created.

You can use partial or lambda to generate a new uuid function.

```
from functools import partial
account_uuid = models.CharField(
    max_length=34, 
    default=partial(make_uuid,'AC')
)
```

Comment: Thank you! Works perfectly... but feels like a hack... I can't quite put my finger on it, but it feels like a workaround to a straightforward mistake I am making else where.